# Callback in google.accounts.oauth2.initCodeClient is called with empty object

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-signin

The callback is supposed to be called with an object, containing things like `authuser`, `code`, `scope`, `scope` etc... Around 6-7 times a day, it's being called with an empty object.

```
async function initClient(
  callback: (googleAuthResponse: GoogleAuthResponse) => void,
) {
  try {
    return (window as any).google.accounts.oauth2.initCodeClient({
      client_id: GOOGLE_SIGNIN_CLIENT_ID,
      scope: 'openid profile email',
      callback,
      error_callback: (error: any) => {
        addAlertMessage({
          type: 'error',
          message: getGoogleErrorMessage(error),
        });
      },
    });
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(
      `Google Client initialization failed with error: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`,
    );
  }
}

load()
    .then(() =>
      initClient((googleAuthResponse: GoogleAuthResponse) => {
        store.dispatch(
          logInWithGoogle({ ...googleAuthResponse, ...partnerData }),
        );
      }),
    )
```

Can anybody recommend something? Does anybody know what's causing it?